# How can I use a variable as column name in mysql / express?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Currently I have this issue, the problem is that the table name gets a set of quotation marks (ad it's a string) and this makes the server crash.

```
const update =  'the name of my column';
const UpdateQuery = `UPDATE scores
    SET ${mysql.escape(update)} = ${mysql.escape(newValue)}
    WHERE score_id = ${mysql.escape(singleScore.score_id)}`;
```

`mysql.escape()` works fine for everything except for the column name.

This is what I get if I console.log the query after injecting the variables:

```
UPDATE scores
SET 'the name of my column' = 1
WHERE score_id = 1
```

Comment: I am but only in the example I wrote here, not in my actual code

Comment: Have you checked the UpdateQuery after the const applied using console log or something to print?

Comment: Yeah, I added it now

Comment: So, the problem is single quote !?

Comment: Yeah that's what's causing the issue

Comment: Just try "var" instead of "const" for the update column

Comment: @TamilvananN that makes no sense. Default to const always.

Comment: @Evert Yess., That doesn't make sense. Sorry... I think the problem is `${mysql.escape(update)}` includes the const value as defined. Try the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using the [mysql NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).

The `escape` method is used for escaping query values. To escape query identifiers (like column names) you should use the `escapeId` method instead. Your code should look like this:

```
const update =  'the name of my column';
const UpdateQuery = `UPDATE scores
    SET ${mysql.escapeId(update)} = ${mysql.escape(newValue)}
    WHERE score_id = ${mysql.escape(singleScore.score_id)}`;
```

Similarly, if you are using replacements, use a double question mark instead of a single to escape identifiers.

```
const update =  'the name of my column';
const UpdateQuery = `UPDATE scores
    SET ?? = ?
    WHERE score_id = ?`;
const replacements = [update, newValue, singleScore.score_id];
```

[See the mysql docs for more details.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers)

Comment: thanks -- swapping out ? with ?? did it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Tamilvanan  solution with a tiny change fixes the issue

```
 db.query(
            'UPDATE scores SET '+update+' = ? Where score_id = ?',
            [newValue, singleScore.score_id],
            (err, result) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log(`Changed ${result.changedRows} row(s)`);
            }
          );
```

Comment: This won't escape the column name, if it had some characters that could cause problems, check out my solution, I think it addresses that problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, I had this problem myself yesterday. I found the solution by accidentally searching for variable table names.

The solution is to query like this:

```js
const columnName =  'the name of my column';
query("UPDATE `scores` SET ?? = ? WHERE `score_id` = ?;", [columnName, singleScore.score_id, newValue]);
```

Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

For weird MySQL column names, you can't put single quotes around them. Single quotes just turn the value into a string.

The backtick is used for this in MySQL. For example

```
UPDATE `table with space` SET `column with space` = 'bar';
```

Comment: To clarify this, in MySQL and most other RDBMS that try to adhere at least partially to the SQL standard; even for non-weird column names, you can't put single quotes around them. Single-quotes are only used for delimiting strings.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. It might work,

```
con.query(
  'UPDATE scores SET '+update+' = ? Where score_id = ?',
  // Old - [${mysql.escape(newValue)}, ${mysql.escape(singleScore.score_id)}],
  /* Update - */ [newValue,singleScore.score_id],
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`Changed ${result.changedRows} row(s)`);
  }
);
```

As per your query, `${mysql.escape(update)}` includes the single quote from the value.

Comment: Thanks ! 
removing the mysql.escape characters works fine.

Comment: Yeah, mysql.escape is not needed if we're using `?`

Comment: Another one way: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlstring#formatting-queries